# Logical error with the statement 'sc.nextLine();'

Tags: string, input

When I run this part of my program, it fails to recognize the two input statements using 'sc.nextLine();', but it accepts an entry for 'sc.next();'. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
String information()
{
    int l;char at;String nam,id,number;long contact;
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter your name");
    nam=sc.nextLine();
    do
    {
        System.out.println("\nPlease enter your contact number");
        contact=sc.nextLong();
        number=Long.toString(contact);
        l=number.length();
        if(l<5||l>8&&l!=10)
            error();
    }
    while(l<5||l>8&&l!=10);
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter your e-mail id");
    id=sc.nextLine();
    int len=id.length();
    for(int k=0;k<len;k++)
    {
        at=id.charAt(k);
        if(Character.isWhitespace(at))
        {
            error();
            break;
        }
    }
    return nam;
}
```

Comment: What is the error given?

Comment: It's a logical error. Hence, when I run it, it says 'Please enter your name', leaves a line and says, 'Please enter your contact number'. Hence, I can't input for the former statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sc.nextLine` above the

```cpp
nam = sc.nextLine();
```

It takes nextLine into an empty line so you need to clear the buffer first.